# Creating Kotlin pojo class for json response containing dynamic objects with array of arrays (Using Retrofit2 for conceiving web services)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

```
{
  "2021-04-24": [
    [
      {
        "match_id": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "ABC",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "aaa",
            "country": "c1"
          },
          {
            "name": "bbb",
            "country": "c2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "match_id": "2",
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "ABC",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "ccc",
            "country": "c2"
          },
          {
            "name": "ddd",
            "country": "c1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "match_id": "3",
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "ABC",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "eee",
            "country": "c2"
          },
          {
            "name": "fff",
            "country": "c4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "match_id": "4",
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "XYZ",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "aaa",
            "country": "c1"
          },
          {
            "name": "bbb",
            "country": "c2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "match_id": "2",
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "XYZ",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "ccc",
            "country": "c2"
          },
          {
            "name": "ddd",
            "country": "c1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "match_id": "3",
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "XYZ",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "eee",
            "country": "c2"
          },
          {
            "name": "fff",
            "country": "c4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ],
  "2021-05-15": [
    [
      {
        "match_id": 1,
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "ABC",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "aaa",
            "country": "c1"
          },
          {
            "name": "bbb",
            "country": "c2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "match_id": "2",
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "ABC",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "ccc",
            "country": "c2"
          },
          {
            "name": "ddd",
            "country": "c1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "match_id": "3",
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "ABC",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "eee",
            "country": "c2"
          },
          {
            "name": "fff",
            "country": "c4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "match_id": "4",
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "XYZ",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "aaa",
            "country": "c1"
          },
          {
            "name": "bbb",
            "country": "c2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "match_id": "2",
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "XYZ",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "ccc",
            "country": "c2"
          },
          {
            "name": "ddd",
            "country": "c1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "match_id": "3",
        "status": "1",
        "venue": "XYZ",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "eee",
            "country": "c2"
          },
          {
            "name": "fff",
            "country": "c4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is the json response, It contains the data of certain matches of a game. The matches are differentiated with respect to date and again sorted with venue. The structure is like dynamic objects with array of arrays. I'm trying to create a pojo class for parsing this response. I'm using Retrofit2.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
data class BasePojo (
    val playersList : List<List<PlayersList>> = listOf()
)

data class PlayersList (
    val match_id : Int = 0,
    val status : Int = 0,
    val venue : String = "",
    val players : List<Players> = listOf()
)

data class Players (
    val name : String = "",
    val country : String = ""
)
```

And modify the code as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use plugin [Json to Kotlin Class](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-)